pure morphism and containment of ideals
Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. An $R$-linear map $f:M\to N$ of $R$-modules is called pure if $f\otimes X:M\otimes_R X \to N\otimes_R X$ is injective for every $R$-module $X$.
Now let $f: R\to R$ be a ring homomorphism such that if we consider the $R$-module $f_* R$ via restriction of scalars, then the $R$-linear map $f: R \to f_* R$ is pure. If $I, J$ are ideals of $R$ such that $f(I)R\subseteq f(J)R$, then is it true that $I\subseteq J$?

Yes, tensor by R/J and use the fact that the resulting morphism is injective.
